# How do I change the help formatter in DSharpPlus

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

So I'm trying the change the ;help command. Usually, when you type the command it returns a built-in help message. I tried using this code but when I use the command it returns nothing:

````cs
public class CustomHelpFormatter: DefaultHelpFormatter 
{
    protected DiscordEmbedBuilder _embed;
    protected StringBuilder _strBuilder;

    public CustomHelpFormatter(CommandContext ctx) : base(ctx) 
    {
        var Rand = new Random();
        _embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder 
        {
            Color = new DiscordColor((byte) Rand.Next(0, 255), (byte) Rand.Next(0, 255), (byte) Rand.Next(0, 255))
        };
        _strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public override BaseHelpFormatter WithCommand(Command command) 
    {
        _embed.Title = "Menu";
        _embed.Description = "```ping```";

        return this;
    }

    public override CommandHelpMessage Build() 
    {
        return new CommandHelpMessage(embed: _embed);
        return new CommandHelpMessage(content: _strBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
````

I also used this code to register the changes:

```cs
Commands.SetHelpFormatter<CustomHelpFormatter>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Bot.cs file you need to disable the built-in help command in your CommandsNextConfiguration like this

```
            var commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration
            {
                StringPrefixes = new string[] { configJson.Prefix },
                EnableMentionPrefix = true,
                EnableDms = true,
                EnableDefaultHelp = false,
            };
```

By setting EnableDefaultHelp to false, you can then create your own help command without having to go through the stuff you did in your code

Example of a help command

```
[Command("help")]
public async Task HelpCommand(CommandContext ctx)
{
    Code whatever you need here. Maybe show an embed message or other
    way to show help information
}
```